# How to retrieve field value from json object when object name has DOT in it

Tags: json, jackson, rest-assured, fasterxml

I want to extract "msg" value from below json using `fasterxml.jackson` - Can anyone suggest me how my model class should look like?

```
{
    "statusCode": 422,
    "error": "Unprocessable Entity",
    "message": "Bad data received",
    "err_data": {
        "payment_details.type": {
            "location": "body",
            "param": "payment_details.type",
            "msg": "Must be either etransfer or cheque"
        }
    }
}
```

This is what I have done, but it is always returning "null" !

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.ALWAYS)
public class MyApiResponse extends ParentResponse implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @JsonProperty("payment_details")
    private PaymentDetails payment_details;

    @JsonProperty("payment_details")
    public PaymentDetails getPayment_details() {
        return payment_details;
    }

    @JsonProperty("payment_details")
    public void setPayment_details(PaymentDetails payment_details) {
        this.payment_details = payment_details;
    }
}
```

`ParentResponse` model class extends `ErrorResponse` model class and this is how it looks like..

This `ErrorResponse` model represents above mentioned JSON.

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class ErrorResponse implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @JsonProperty("statusCode")
    private int statusCode;

    @JsonProperty("error")
    private String error;

    @JsonProperty("message")
    private String message;

    @JsonProperty("err_data")
    private ErrData err_data;

    @JsonProperty("statusCode")
    public int getStatusCode() {
        return statusCode;
    }

    @JsonProperty("statusCode")
    public void setStatusCode(int statusCode) {
        this.statusCode = statusCode;
    }

    @JsonProperty("message")
    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    @JsonProperty("message")
    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    @JsonProperty("error")
    public String getError() {
        return error;
    }

    @JsonProperty("error")
    public void setError(String error) {
        this.error = error;
    }

    @JsonProperty("err_data")
    public ErrData getErr_data() {
        return err_data;
    }

    @JsonProperty("err_data")
    public void setErr_data(ErrData err_data) {
        this.err_data = err_data;
    }
}
```

`err_data` object is represented by below model class.

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.ALWAYS)
public class ErrData implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @JsonProperty("email")
    private Email email;

    @JsonProperty("payment_details.type")
    private PaymentDetailsType payment_details_type;

    @JsonProperty("email")
    public Email getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    @JsonProperty("email")
    public void setEmail(Email email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @JsonProperty("payment_details.type")
    public PaymentDetailsType getPayment_details_type() {
        return payment_details_type;
    }

    @JsonProperty("payment_details.type")
    public void setPayment_details_type(PaymentDetailsType payment_details_type) {
        this.payment_details_type = payment_details_type;
    }
}
```

`payment_details.type` object represented by below class.

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.ALWAYS)
public class PaymentDetailsType extends ErrorMessage implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

}

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.ALWAYS)
public class Email extends ErrorMessage implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

}
```

And finally `ErrorMessage` which is extended by `PaymentDetailsType` as below.

```
@JsonPropertyOrder({"location", "param", "value", "msg"})
public class ErrorMessage implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @JsonProperty("location")
    private String location;

    @JsonProperty("param")
    private String param;

    @JsonProperty("value")
    private String value;

    @JsonProperty("msg")
    private String msg;

    @JsonProperty("location")
    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    @JsonProperty("location")
    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    @JsonProperty("param")
    public String getParam() {
        return param;
    }

    @JsonProperty("param")
    public void setParam(String param) {
        this.param = param;
    }

    @JsonProperty("value")
    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    @JsonProperty("value")
    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @JsonProperty("msg")
    public String getMsg() {
        return msg;
    }

    @JsonProperty("msg")
    public void setMsg(String msg) {
        this.msg = msg;
    }
}
```

And finally I am trying to get "msg" field value as below -

```
new Gson().fromJson(response.asString(), MyApiResponse.class).getErr_data().getPayment_details_type().getMsg();
```

I think there is something wrong with this one - Not sure how to define getter method if field name in json as . (dot).

```
@JsonProperty("payment_details.type")
public PaymentDetailsType getPayment_details_type() {
    return payment_details_type;
}
```

Similar to above, I am doing it for below json to retrieve "msg" value and it is working fine.

```
{
    "statusCode": 422,
    "error": "Unprocessable Entity",
    "message": "Bad data received",
    "err_data": {
        "email": {
            "location": "body",
            "param": "email",
            "value": "test @ com",
            "msg": "Must be a valid email"
        }
    }
}
```

This is returning correct "msg" value.

```
new Gson().fromJson(response.asString(), MyApiResponse.class).getErr_data().getEmail().getMsg();
```

Please suggest!

Thank you.

Comment: We can do it simple with Gson library. Let me know if you want me to answer.

Comment: thanks @learner8269 for replying. I don't want to write parser to read json, I feel jackson is the simplest way. but yes, please answer it and I will see if I can make use of it. thanks

Comment: Jackson can parse properties with dots in the name and `@JsonProperty` from Jackson is the way to handle this. The examples you post use `new Gson()`. That's from a different library that doesn't take `@JsonProperty` into account.

Comment: @ManosNikolaidis, are you suggesting to use `objectMapper` instead of `GSon`? I found `GSon` more easy and simple to use.. could you pls suggest me what changes I should do, may be one quick simple example? thanks!

Comment: In case you are not aware, `ObjectMapper` and `Gson` are from different libraries. You are asking for a solution using _"fasterxml.jackson"_ which means you intend to use `ObjectMapper`. The code `new Gson()` implies using Gson library not Jackson. Gson will not see `@JsonProperty("payment_details.type")`

Comment: Also have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Avoid posting all the code for all your classes. Just a small example reproducing only the problem you are having with dots in the name. Look at my answer for what a minimal question might look like.

Comment: Thank you. Purpose of having some of the sample code was to also get it reviewed and I wanted to make sure I am not doing any mistakes in any of these classes/model. I will look at you’re answer below. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a minimal example showing how to parse a JSON with Jackson, where the property names may contain dots:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import java.io.IOException;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String json = "{" +
                      "    \"payment_details.type\": {" +
                      "        \"location\": \"body\"" +
                      "    }" +
                      "}";
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Response response = mapper.readValue(json, Response.class);
        System.out.println(response.getPaymentDetailsType().getLocation());
    }
}

class Response {
    @JsonProperty("payment_details.type")
    private PaymentDetailsType paymentDetailsType;

    public PaymentDetailsType getPaymentDetailsType() { return paymentDetailsType; }
}

class PaymentDetailsType {
    private String location;

    public String getLocation() { return location; }
}
```

Note that you only need `@JsonProperty` when the expected property name in JSON cannot be deduced from a setter or variable name

Comment: Thank you. I will try this out. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Its also working with @JsonProperty.
You just have to escape the dot:

```
@JsonProperty("payment_details\\.type")
```